# Showing the keyboard programmatically does not adjust the window

Tags: android

The title sums it well. I'm requesting focus for an `EditText` showing the soft keyboard programmatically. The `EditText` gets focus as requested, and the keyboard is open, but the window is not being adjusted accordingly. Clicking on the `EditText` directly works fine.

Here's the code:

```
textView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                editText.requestFocus();

                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.showSoftInput(editText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
            }
        }
    });
```

Any workaround?

**Edit:**
I've already tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` and `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` on the `<activity ..>` in the manifest file. Neither did the trick.

**Edit 2:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/edittext_appendable_layout"
    style="@style/PGTheme.EditText.Dark"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:addStatesFromChildren="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_appendable_text"
        style="@style/PGTheme.EditText.Dark.NoUnderline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_size"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/edittext_appendable_textview"
        style="@style/PGTheme.EditText.Dark.NoUnderline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/view_size"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingEnd="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="0dp"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit 3:**
Forgot to mention: after the `EditText` gets focus and I start typing, it adjusts normally.

Comment: Did you set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`on the `<activity ..>` in the manifest?

Comment: I have set `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"`, which didn't work. Setting `adjustResize` messes the layout, and the `EditText` doesn't move up.

Comment: Post your layout XML if you need help. A general tip is to surround your layout with a `ScrollView`.

Comment: I've edited the post with the xml layout. I don't think that's the problem, though, because it doesn't work only when I show the keyboard programmatically.